# How to get last value from a table category wise?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with retrieving the last value of every category from my table which should not be sorted. For example i want the daily inventory value of nov-1 last appearance in the table without sorting the column daily inventory i.e "471". Is there a way to achieve this?
similarly i need to get the value of the next week's last daily inventory value and i should be able to do this for multiple items in the table too.

p.s: nov-1 represents nov-1 st week

[image: example table]

Comment: What determines the "last" row in your image? I see nothing you can `ORDER BY` than maintains that order. If you have nothing you can `ORDER BY` to maintain that order, then none of those rows are the "last" row; as they have no order. Also, please do replace that image with formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: Nothing in your data is called "category".  I'm confused.

Comment: Hi, there's no row id, or entry date (or any date reference - aside from the week) to signify some sort of progression or order?  Effectively what @Larnu was asking.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I get where you're going here, as I made the assumption that OP wanted to group by week (what OP posted as "category"), and get the last dailyinventory here.  OP should confirm this, and I shouldn't assume.

Comment: yes that is what i want to find out and the category i meant was week. Thanks @TinyHaitian

Comment: I dont have any primary key for the above table , should i have to combine both week and item and use it as a composite key? My use case is to find the inventory of each item at the end of every week and each row in the above table corresponds to a day in that week

Comment: I don't think that'd be enough, as WEEK and ITEM, in and of itself, will not give you unique keys (just unique sets); you'd be right back to square one.  You'd need another column to force uniqueness AND order.  Or... just another column that will determine row uniqueness.  Only then, you'd be able to get your last row per group.

Comment: will i be able to achieve what i need if i introduce a column id ? If so how can i do it?

Comment: Short answer, yes.   However, is this all that's in this table?

Comment: If you introduce an ID column that *retains* the current order, you could do something, yes. But you'll likely need to reinsert all your data in order from where ever it originally came from.

Comment: Have you had any updates?

Answer (score 0):

**Question from comments of initial post:** *will I be able to achieve what I need if I introduce a column id? If so, how can I do it?*

Here's *a way* to do it (no guarantee that it's the *most efficient way* to do it)...

```
;WITH SetID AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Week ORDER BY Week) AS rowid, * FROM <TableName>
),
MaxRow AS
(
    SELECT LastRecord = MAX(rowid), Week
    FROM SetID
    GROUP BY Week
)
SELECT a.* 
FROM SetID a
INNER JOIN MaxRow b
    ON a.rowid = b.LastRecord
    AND b.Week = a.Week
ORDER BY a.Week
```

I feel like there's more to the table though, and this is also untested on large amounts of data.   I'd be afraid that a different RowID could be potentially assigned upon each run.  (I haven't used *ROW_NUMBER()* enough to know if this would throw unexpected data.)

I suppose this example is to enforce the idea that, if you had a dedicated rowID on the table, it's possible. Also, I believe @Larnu's comment to you on your original post - introducing an ID column that *retains* current order, but reinserting all your data - is a concern too.

Here's a SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04eca/4).